# How to take square root in c#

Tags: c#, math

I have a formula that I want to write in C#. Please find a mistake if any... [image: Formula Picture].
I'm writing in my code same like this:

```
Xopt = 293.94 * Math.Sqrt(HDD * Cfuel * PWF * K / H4 * Cy * n) - K * Rwt;
```

Unfortunately, the results from this are not the same as the formula. How can I fix it?

Comment: Should be `Xopt = 293.94 * Math.Sqrt((HDD * Cfuel * PWF * K) / (H4 * Cy * n)) - K * Rwt`

Comment: I really don't understand why anybody would vote to close this. It's a very straightforward question with code. There's nothing confusing about it. There's no information missing.

Comment: @JoePhillips Image instead of text for the formula is my guess (not my downvote or close vote). This is a case where I sympathize. If it were that easy to show the formula as text, the code would be right, too, and there'd be no question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs either more parentheses or to break up the calculation over multiple statements (or both). Otherwise, the square root expression only divides by `H4` and then multiples that result by `Cy` and `n`.

```
var numerator = HDD * Cfuel * PWF * K; 
var denominator = H4 * Cy * n;
Xopt = 293.94 * Math.Sqrt(numerator / denominator) - (k * Rwt);
```

Even better if you know enough about why the formula is what it is to give the numerator and denominator values meaningful names.

Comment: I like to see them getting proper names like this. The only downside that I'm aware of is it causes more allocations which some people may complain about

Comment: I don't know about that. The "extra" variables are likely one of: optimized away by the compiler, held in the stack frame for the method anyway, or the larger expression would also have needed temp values of it's own. It would be interested to see an IL deconstruction.

Comment: This diff tool is terrible but you can get the raw comparison here. There does seem to be some difference although I can't really tell how much: https://www.diffchecker.com/4AHSMF1C

Comment: But you're right, no "allocations" (I didn't understand what I was saying at the time)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a set of parentheses around the denominator. Without them, everything inside the sqrt is getting computed left to right.

```
Xopt = 293.94 * Math.Sqrt(HDD * Cfuel * PWF * K / (H4 * Cy * n)) - (K * Rwt);
```

Also a set around the last factor. Thanks Joel.

Comment: Based on the image, I bet it needs parents around that last subtraction op, too.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yup. Good catch. I parsed all that as one variable based on the image, not as two based on the code snippet. Fixed.